# Is there a query which select which customers have bought a specific product and what other products did these same customers buy?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, on one table has the transactions (ProductId | TransactionId | CustomerID), and the other one has the products description (ProductId | ProductName).

I have tried using `INNER JOIN`, but only managed to select the customers who have bought that specific product.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Show the query you have tried, the result you get and the result you want. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query on SQL related questions and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following table:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN transactions;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id            | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ProductId     | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TransactionId | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CustomerId    | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

You first read the row with the product and customer you want:

```
SELECT
    t.TransactionId
FROM
    transactions t
WHERE
    t.CustomerId = 4 AND
    t.ProductId = 9;
```

This would generate something like this:

```
+---------------+
| TransactionId |
+---------------+
|             7 |
+---------------+
```

Then you use a `JOIN` on the same table to get all the rows with that transaction id (I used the alias `i` as in "items").

```
SELECT
    i.ProductId,
    i.TransactionId,
    i.CustomerId
FROM
    transactions t
JOIN
    transactions i ON t.TransactionId = i.TransactionId
WHERE
    t.CustomerId = 4 AND
    t.ProductId = 9;
```

You might get a result like this:

```
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| Id | ProductId | TransactionId | CustomerId |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |         3 |             7 |          4 |
|  2 |         4 |             7 |          4 |
|  3 |         9 |             7 |          4 |
+----+-----------+---------------+------------+
```

From there you can access/join the `products` table to get the names.

Keep in mind that your table structure does not fit the [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). You might want to create tables like this:

```
transactions
    - Id
    - CustomerId
    - OrderDate
    - [...]

products
    - Id
    - Name

transactionItems
    - Id
    - TransactionId
    - ProductId
    - Amount (?)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the bad format of the question, this was literally my first post on stackoverflow.